# Need a javascript technical explanation about Function.__proto__?

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log(Function instanceof Object) // true
console.log(Function.__proto__ === Object.prototype) // false
console.log(Function.__proto__ == Function.prototype) // true
```

What's the technical explanation on why on line (2.) is "false" when Function is an instance of Object?

Comment: `Function.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype`, ["The `instanceof` operator tests whether the prototype property of a constructor appears **anywhere** in the prototype chain of an object."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Comment: @ASDFGerte that should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__proto__` references the *immediate* prototype object in the prototype chain. As you can see from #3, the prototype of `Function` is `Function.prototype`. Although a function *is* a type of object, `Object.prototype` is *higher* on the prototype chain - they're not the same, hence `(Function.__proto__ === Object.prototype)` is false:

```js
console.log(Function.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype);

// Same as:

console.log(Function.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype);
```

`Function` extends `Object`, as you can see.

Also, you might note that it's probably preferable to use `getPrototypeOf`. From MDN:

> Warning: While Object.prototype.**proto** is supported today in most browsers, its existence and exact behavior has only been standardized in the ECMAScript 2015 specification as a legacy feature to ensure compatibility for web browsers. For better support, it is recommended that only Object.getPrototypeOf() be used instead.